# How add to DataTrigger property Visability collapse/visible?

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml

I want to create a beautiful page that can change the form when I choose the role.

When I choose user role, I hide the developer fields and I want to resize form like in a picture

[image]

if I choose developer the form should have fool form like in a picture

[image]

it's a good way for me if I will add new role with the field in future

but I don't have any idea how to make this resizing?

I have just code how to hide or show the company fields. I spend much time to find some information about how to do that but unsuccessfully.

```
 <Page.Resources>

    <Storyboard x:Key="OpenMenu">
        <DoubleAnimationUsingKeyFrames Storyboard.TargetProperty="(FrameworkElement.Width)" >
            <EasingDoubleKeyFrame KeyTime="0" Value="0"/>
            <EasingDoubleKeyFrame KeyTime="0:0:0.5" Value="250"/>
        </DoubleAnimationUsingKeyFrames>
    </Storyboard>

    <Storyboard x:Key="CloseMenu">
        <DoubleAnimationUsingKeyFrames Storyboard.TargetProperty="(FrameworkElement.Width)" >
            <EasingDoubleKeyFrame KeyTime="0" Value="250"/>
            <EasingDoubleKeyFrame KeyTime="0:0:0.5" Value="0"/>
        </DoubleAnimationUsingKeyFrames>
    </Storyboard>

    <Style TargetType="{x:Type TextBox}" x:Key="companyStyle" BasedOn="{StaticResource MaterialDesignFloatingHintTextBox}" >
        <Style.Triggers>

            <DataTrigger Binding="{Binding Path=SelectedValue, ElementName=comboBoxRole}" Value="AppDeveloper">
                <DataTrigger.EnterActions>
                    <BeginStoryboard Name="sb" Storyboard="{StaticResource OpenMenu}"/>
                </DataTrigger.EnterActions>
                <DataTrigger.ExitActions>
                    <RemoveStoryboard BeginStoryboardName="sb" />
                </DataTrigger.ExitActions>
            </DataTrigger>

            <DataTrigger Binding="{Binding Path=SelectedValue, ElementName=comboBoxRole}" Value="EndUser">
                <DataTrigger.EnterActions>
                    <BeginStoryboard Name="sb2" Storyboard="{StaticResource CloseMenu}"/>
                </DataTrigger.EnterActions>
                <DataTrigger.ExitActions>
                    <RemoveStoryboard BeginStoryboardName="sb2" />
                </DataTrigger.ExitActions>
            </DataTrigger>

        </Style.Triggers>
    </Style>

</Page.Resources>
```

and need to use animations to make this resizing smooth, maybe someone knows how to realize it or read about that.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to be tactful about this, as we have to deal with two things;

1. When window resizes, you need the two sections to expand/collapse accordingly.
2. Allow for animation.

So let's get to the first one, how to design the window. The Left Hand Side (LHS) of your form is common to both, and must always be displayed. The Right Hand Side (RHS) is only visible when the selected user is a dev. This means, you need your LHS to fill up the width of the form, and the RHS to take up only as much space as needed when visible. This is a great occasion to make use of the `Width=Auto`. I'd have a `2 x 2` grid, with the top row spanning both columns and have the `ComboBox` there, and then your two sets of `TextBox` controls in each column in the second row. I'm using `Border` controls to denote those two. So, I'd use the first `ColumnDefinition` without setting the `Width` property, and the second one with `Width=Auto`.

```
<Grid Margin="10">
    <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
        <ColumnDefinition/>
        <ColumnDefinition Width="Auto"/>
    </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
    <Grid.RowDefinitions>
        <RowDefinition Height="Auto"/>
        <RowDefinition/>
    </Grid.RowDefinitions>

    <ComboBox Grid.Column="0" Grid.Row="0" Grid.ColumnSpan="2"
              Width="100" Height="24" Margin="4"
              HorizontalAlignment="Center" VerticalAlignment="Center"/>

    <Border Grid.Column="0" Grid.Row="1"
            Margin="10"
            Background="LightSkyBlue" CornerRadius="4"/>

    <Border Grid.Column="1" Grid.Row="1" 
            Margin="10" Width="150"
            Background="LightGreen" CornerRadius="4"/>
</Grid>
```

Notice that the LHS border doesn't have a width specified, as it will take up the entire available width, and the RHS will have a set width of `150` in this case. It should look like this:

[image]

Now, I'm trying to accomplish two things here.

1. When uses selects `AppDeveloper`, both RHS and LHS will be visible. When the `EndUser` is selected, the RHS border (green one) `Visibility=Collapsed` so that it becomes invisible AND doesn't take up any space.

   - For this I'm going to use a `BooleanToVisibilityConverter`, and bind the `Visibility` property of the RHS border to a `bool` variable in your code behind named `ExtraDetails`.
2. At the same time, when `EndUser` is selected, the `Window` width is shortened, and it will happen with an animation. Similarly, when `AppDeveloper` is selected the window width expands to it full size, again with an animation.

   - Here, I'm going to use `Storyboard` class, and set an animation that changes the `Width` of the window based on time.

Additionally, I'm going to use two `public` member variables, a list to populate the combo box and a selected item to represent the selected item in the combo. Note that the main window's `Name` property is important for the animation.

So when everything is put together, your `XAML` would look like this:

```
<Window ...
        Name="mainWin"
        Title="MainWindow" Height="300" Width="400">
    <Window.Resources>
        <BooleanToVisibilityConverter x:Key="BoolToVis" />
        <Storyboard x:Key="showWin">
            <DoubleAnimation Storyboard.TargetName="mainWin" Storyboard.TargetProperty="Width" Duration="0:0:.5" To="400" BeginTime="0:0:0"/>
        </Storyboard>

        <Storyboard x:Key="hideWin">
            <DoubleAnimation Storyboard.TargetName="mainWin" Storyboard.TargetProperty="Width" Duration="0:0:.5" To="200" BeginTime="0:0:0"/>
        </Storyboard>
    </Window.Resources>
    <Grid Margin="10">
        <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
            <ColumnDefinition/>
            <ColumnDefinition Width="Auto"/>
        </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
        <Grid.RowDefinitions>
            <RowDefinition Height="Auto"/>
            <RowDefinition/>
        </Grid.RowDefinitions>

        <ComboBox Grid.Column="0" Grid.Row="0" Grid.ColumnSpan="2"
                  Width="100" Height="24" Margin="4"
                  HorizontalAlignment="Center" VerticalAlignment="Center"
                  ItemsSource="{Binding ComboItems}"
                  SelectedValue="{Binding SelectedItem}"
                  SelectionChanged="ComboBox_SelectionChanged"/>

        <Border Grid.Column="0" Grid.Row="1"
                Margin="10"
                Background="LightSkyBlue" CornerRadius="4"/>

        <Border Grid.Column="1" Grid.Row="1" 
                Margin="10" Width="150"
                Background="LightGreen" CornerRadius="4"
                Visibility="{Binding Path=ExtraDetails, Converter={StaticResource BoolToVis}}"/>
    </Grid>
</Window>
```

And the code behind:

```
public partial class MainWindow : Window, INotifyPropertyChanged
{
    public event PropertyChangedEventHandler PropertyChanged;

    protected void OnPropertyChanged(string propertyName)
    {
        PropertyChanged?.Invoke(this, new PropertyChangedEventArgs(propertyName));
    }

    private List<string> _comboItems;

    public List<string> ComboItems
    {
        get { return _comboItems; }
        set
        {
            if (value != _comboItems)
            {
                _comboItems = value;
                OnPropertyChanged("ComboItems");
            }
        }
    }

    private string _selectedItem;

    public string SelectedItem
    {
        get { return _selectedItem; }
        set
        {
            if (value != _selectedItem)
            {
                _selectedItem = value;
                OnPropertyChanged("SelectedItem");
            }
        }
    }

    private bool _extraDetails;

    public bool ExtraDetails
    {
        get { return _extraDetails; }
        set
        {
            if (value != _extraDetails)
            {
                _extraDetails = value;
                OnPropertyChanged("ExtraDetails");
            }
        }
    }

    public Storyboard showWin;
    public Storyboard hideWin;

    public MainWindow()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
        PopulateCombo();
        showWin = (Storyboard)Resources["showWin"];
        hideWin = (Storyboard)Resources["hideWin"];
        DataContext = this;
    }

    private void PopulateCombo()
    {
        ComboItems = new List<string>
        {
            "EndUser",
            "AppDeveloper"
        };
        SelectedItem = ComboItems.Last();
    }

    private void ComboBox_SelectionChanged(object sender, SelectionChangedEventArgs e)
    {
        if (SelectedItem == "AppDeveloper")
        {
            ExtraDetails = true;
            BeginStoryboard(showWin);
        }
        else
        {
            ExtraDetails = false;
            BeginStoryboard(hideWin);
        }
    }
}
```

Notice that in the constructor, I 'acquire' the two `Storyboard` resources defined in the `XAML`. Then in the `ComboBox_SelectionChanged` event handler, I use the appropriate `Storyboard` to resize the window with an animation. By setting `ExtraDetails` at the same time, you also show/hide the RHS green section.

Comment: Thank you, It 's a really good and interesting solution! I integrate your logic with changing the property `Visibility` with my animation logic. It helps me create a good one solution!)